# Better way of performing dynamic conditional searching in TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a large-ish query here that has several params, and for each one, the query only differs by one portion of the `where` clause, like so:

`CASE WHEN @IncludeNames = 1 AND @NameFilter IS NULL THEN`

`(SELECT blah FROM blahBlah`

```
    INNER JOIN ... 
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE blahBlah.Id = x.Id)
```

`WHEN @IncludeNames = 1 AND @NameFilter IS NOT NULL THEN`

`(SELECT blah FROM blahBlah`

```
    INNER JOIN ... 
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    WHERE blahBlah.Id = x.Id
    AND table2.Id = @NameFilter
```

It goes on like that for several instances, differing only by one condition on the where clause.

Keep in mind this is in the middle of a larger select.

Is there a good way of cleaning this up, without placing it all into one large concatenated sql string and running `exec` on it, or using something absurd like multiple stored procs per block, as shown here: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/7305/dynamic-search-conditions-in-tsql/7/

Server is SQL Server 2008 R2.  TIA!

Comment: Does it never check if `@IncludeNames = 0`?  What happens if that is the case?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: Is it your intent to allow for the application of more than one filter at a time, e.g. by Name and ShoeSize?

Comment: @X-Zero, it does check that case, I just neglected to paste a snippet of that here.  Thanks for asking though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up your query with an option of all or specific values for each clause e.g.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM   x
WHERE  (x.id = @NameFilter
OR     @NameFilter is null)
AND    (x.typeId = @typeFilter
OR     -1 =  @typeFilter)
AND    (x.date = @date
OR     @date is null)
AND    (x.someStingType = @someStringType
Or     '' = @someStringType)
```

This should allow you to concatenate your clauses into a single select statement.  Each parameter may apply a filter or have no effect (if set to the default such as null, empty string or -1).

Comment: This might be easier to read, and easier on the optimizer, if the various filter conditions are spread out into the appropriate ON clauses of the INNER JOINs.